# Get data on click of load more button from start index to end index using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using WEBAPI and LINQ to get the data from SQL,I have a Load More button in my page, when i click - it should bring 20 records each time, I am using Start Index and End Index has my table column ID which is primary Key.

When I click the load More Button, I'll get the last Id i.e, last data ID from the list view, I am using that Id has my start index,now my problem is when I click on load more it brings 20 data but previous data gets be erased. I need to get 20+20=40 data, when I click load more button for first time.

how to achieve this? Please find my code below

```
          //Linq//
          public dynamic getALlImage(int userID, int LastImageID)
   {
       //here LastImageId is my Listview Last data ImageID
         if  (LastImageID!=0)
          {
   startIndex= LastImageID+20;
   EndIndex=LastImageID-20;
 }
   else
 {
  startIndex= 20;
   EndIndex=0;  
 }

  GetAllListFields = (from user in dbContext.UserTable
                  join img in dbContext.ImageTable on user.userId equals img.userID into UserVoice
                  from Image in UserVoice.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where (Image.imgId <= startIndex && Image.imgId >= EndIndex && Image.userID == userID && Image.IsStatusChecked == false)
                  orderby feeds.CreatedAt descending
                  select new
                  {
                       PostImage = Image == null ? 0 : Image.ImageID,
                      Image = usrMessae==null?0: Image.userMessage,
                      createdAt = feeds == null ? DateTime.UtcNow : feeds.CreatedAt,
                      UserId = userdata == null ? 0 : userdata.userId,
                      Name = userdata == null ? " " : userdata.Name,
                      username = userdata == null ? " " : userdata.userName,
               Email = userdata == null ? " " : userdata.emailID,
                    }).Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.createdAt).Take(startIndex).ToList();
     } 


   //HTML//
   <div data-role="view"> 
   <div>
   <ul  data-role="listview"   data-bind="foreach:ImageList">
   <li>
   <div data-bind="text:userID"></div>
   <div data-bind="text:userName"></div>
   <div data-bind="text:UserImageSrc"></div>
   <div data-bind="text:ImageId></div>
   <div data-bind="text:PostImageSrc"></div>
   <div >
   <button data-bind="click:getLoadMoreImageData">Load More</button>
  </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>

      //Knockout Js
  function UserImageViewModel()
    {
        self=this;
      var lastModelValue = (self.FeedPostdata()      [self.FeedPostdata().length - 1]);
      var lastPostImageId = (lastModelValue.ImageId())

     //On Load More click  last Image ID      
     self.getLoadMoreImageData=function()
     {     
       $('#loading').show();
       var UserModel = { userID:userID,ImageId:lastPostImageId}
       jQuery.support.cors = true;
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: serverUrl + 'api/xxx/xxx',
        data: UserModel,
        success: function (data) {
        self.ImageList($.map(data, function (item) {
                return new ImageModel(item);
        }));},
        complete: function () {
            $('#loading').hide();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);} });}}


    // On Page Load  without last Image ID  
      self.getALlUSerImage=function()
     {

        $('#loading').show();
        var UserModel = { userID: userID}
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: serverUrl + 'api/xxx/xxx',
        data: UserModel,
        success: function (data) {
        self.ImageList($.map(data, function (item) {
                return new ImageModel(item);
        }));},
        complete: function () {
            $('#loading').hide();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);} });
            }}
            }


           //Model//
          function ImageModel(item)
          {
            self.userId=ko.observable(item.userId);
            self.userName=ko.observable(item.UserName);
            self.UserImageSrc = ko.computed(function () {
            return "data:" + self.UserImageSrcType() + ";base64," + self.UserImageSrcBase64();});   

            self.ImageID=ko.observable(item.ImageId)
            self.PostImageSrc = ko.computed(function () {
            return "data:" + self.PostImageType() + ";base64," +  self.PostImageBase64();});                      
          }

       $(document).ready(function () {
       ViewModel = new UserImageViewModel();
       ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare one variable and assign initial data to it. After every successful call of ajax apend response to that variable and pass that variable's value to your model.